# Python selenium webdriver - textbox and button won't work

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I have been playing around with selenium webdriver library for python, I have some programming knowledge but almost none when related to webpages etc.

I am trying to login to this website https://freebitco.in/ I click on the login button, fill the textboxes and then click on the button with selenium but the page just refreshes leaving the inputs blank and nothing happens.

I have tried to manually (ctrl+V) inputing the text and then clicking on the button with selenium, in that case it works. I would love an answer for this fenomenon. I would also like to know how can a webpage differentiate between bot input and user input, from my point of view (no webpage knowledge) I can only see it being able to work with the guest timing etc to tell it's a bot or not, how can it see it is a bot writing in this textboxes? (if it is the case).

Thank you for your answers and forgive my poor english skills. (:

This is my code:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('login_menu_button').click()
driver.find_element_by_id('login_form_btc_address').send_keys(address) 
driver.find_element_by_id('login_form_password').send_keys(password)
driver.find_element_by_id('login_button').click()
```

this is for the textboxes:

```
<input type="text" name="btc_address" id="login_form_btc_address">
```

and this is for the button

```
<input type="text" name="btc_address" id="login_form_btc_address">
```

Comment: for some reason this didn't appear:<input type="submit" value="LOGIN!" id="login_button" class="button expand" style="margin:0;">

Comment: <input type="text" name="btc_address" id="login_form_btc_address">

Comment: web page could be checking for clicks or key presses

Comment: When I run your code in a Firefox driver I'm able to successfully log in.

Comment: I am loggin from firefox too with no success, why could that be?

Answer (score 0):

From what I see on that page:

```
<li class="login_menu_button active">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);">LOGIN</a>
</li>
```

So even though you are clicking on top menu, I think you are not opening login form Try to change the first click to be on link element:

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text('LOGIN').click()
```

Also you will probably need to synchronize between clicks (i.e. check that what you expected indeed happened)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think I have pinpointed the problem, but not fixed it yet and specially dont know why it is happening. If I login from selenium then execute my script, it doesn't work but if I open the driver with selenium, go to the website manually and then login with selenium, it works. when I put the web address like 'http://www.freebitco.in/' it doesn't work, when I input it like www.freebitco.in it works, haven't figured out how to do this with selenium yet.